# How to configure Struts Framework to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, struts2

I would like to add the struts framework to my eclipse helios j2ee version.
Plese give me the guidance regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple google search: [struts.apache.org](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/eclipse.html) [java.dzone.com](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27)

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a new Java EE project in Eclipse.
2. Download the Apache Struts framework from its [website](http://struts.apache.org/downloads.html).
3. If you use Maven as your build system, add the Structs artifact (see [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html)). If you use another build system, unzip the downloaded framework and add these files to the `WEB_INF/lib` folder of your application:

   - commons-fileupload-X.X.X.jar
   - commons-io-X.X.X.jar
   - commons-logging-X.X.X.jar
   - commons-logging-api.X.X.jar
   - freemarker-X.X.X.jar
   - ognl-X.X.X.jar
   - struts2-core-X.X.X.X.jar
   - xwork-core-X.X.X.jar
   - javassist-3.7.ga.jar
4. Configure the Web application so that the Struts framework will handle all page requests by adding these lines to the `web.xml` file:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
5. Create the `struts.xml` configuration file.
6. Create the JSPs you need.
7. Build the application.

Source (and further information): http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-with-artifacts-in-web-inf-lib-and-use-ant-to-build-the-application.html

One more jar you need to add that is 
**commons-lang3-x.x.jar**